# Select all records of type 'x' that are the highest 'version'

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Given table:

```
Agreement:
    id: int
    type: string
    version: int
```

Given Records like:

```
1 | Terms | 1
2 | Terms | 2
3 | Privacy | 1
```

I'd like a query that outputs:

```
2 | Terms | 2
3 | Privacy | 1
```

I've tried all manner of distinct and self joins to max(version), I just can't seem to crack it.

Comment: Why do all the rows have the same id?

Comment: I was typing fast.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be to use the `rank` window function:

```
SELECT id, type, version
FROM   (SELECT id, type, version, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY version DESC) AS rk
        FROM   agreement) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work:

```
 select max(id) , type , max(version) from Agreement
 group by type
```

Comment: This didn't seem to filter the rows at all

Comment: This would work with the OP's original data, but having the same id on all the rows turned out to be a typo - see the comments on the question. With the updated data, this response is no longer correct.

Comment: Apologies, that was my bad :(

Comment: I edited the answer, any way, the question is still ambiguous, I had my assumptions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.version
FROM Agreement AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT type, MAX(version) AS maxV
            FROM Agreement
            GROUP BY type) t 
ON t.type = a.type AND a.version = t.maxV
```

This query uses a derived table containing the `MAX(version)` per `type`. Joining to this derived table we can get all rows of the original table having the maximum version per `type`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6bbf4/2)

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql:

select * from agreement a where id in (select id from agreement b where a.type=b.type order by id desc limit 1)

Result:

2 | Terms | 2

3 | Privacy | 1